# Dictionary of dictionary - Get 2nd keys

Tags: python, python-2.x, hash-map

I have a dictionary of dictionary such as `d` below, and I would like to get the list of all keys but not on the first level (i.e. `ABC`, `DEF`) but the one at the second level (i.e `0` and `1` for `ABC` ; `1` and `2` for `DEF`...)

I got this small code that does the job by reading all the dictionaries and by saving the keys (of second level):

```
d = {
    'ABC' : {'0' : [(1,0.5), (2, 0.25)], '1' : [(1,0.4), (3,0.35)]},
    'DEF' : {'1' : [(1,0.5), (4, 0.15)], '2' : [(2,0.3), (3,0.25)]},
    'GHI' : {'0' : [(3,0.2), (4, 0.05)], '2' : [(2,0.2), (2,0.25)]},
}

keys2 = []
for small_d in d.itervalues():
    keys2.extend(small_d.keys())

print set(keys2)
# set(['1', '0', '2'])
```

But I'm sure there is a more pythonic way to do it (and more efficient), any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a shorter (*pythonic*) way to do this using set comprehensions:

```
d = {
    'ABC' : {'0' : [(1,0.5), (2, 0.25)], '1' : [(1,0.4), (3,0.35)]},
    'DEF' : {'1' : [(1,0.5), (4, 0.15)], '2' : [(2,0.3), (3,0.25)]},
    'GHI' : {'0' : [(3,0.2), (4, 0.05)], '2' : [(2,0.2), (2,0.25)]},
}
print {j for i in d.itervalues() for j in i}
# set(['1', '0', '2'])
```

Then if you just want a `list` object you can use `list()` to convert the `set` to list.

---

More, in your example you could just make `keys2` a `set` to begin with and call `keys2.add` instead of `extend`.

---

And some benchmarks from your solution, mine and other answers:

```
import timeit
from itertools import chain


def m1(d):
    return {j for i in d.itervalues() for j in i}


def m2(d):
    keys2 = []
    for small_d in d.itervalues():
        keys2.extend(small_d.keys())

    return set(keys2)


def m3(d):
    return set(chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues()))


def m4(d):
    keys2 = set([])
    for small_d in d.itervalues():
        keys2.update(small_d.keys())
    return keys2


d = {
    'ABC': {'0': [(1, 0.5), (2, 0.25)], '1': [(1, 0.4), (3, 0.35)]},
    'DEF': {'1': [(1, 0.5), (4, 0.15)], '2': [(2, 0.3), (3, 0.25)]},
    'GHI': {'0': [(3, 0.2), (4, 0.05)], '2': [(2, 0.2), (2, 0.25)]},
}

print(timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import m1, d', number=100000000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import m2, d', number=100000000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import m3, d', number=100000000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup='from __main__ import m4, d', number=100000000))
```

> ```
> 0.00136395591689003
> 0.0012866411345431158
> 0.0011429587956683193
> 0.0011374851827588035
> ```

Comment: Since you’re using `itervalues` everywhere else, you might as well use it in `m1`. It might actually be a little bit faster too.

Comment: Good call Matthias, I'll amend it when I'll have the time

Comment: For a better comparison you might want to try larger dictionaries since the differences in the current benchmark are miniscule at best.

Answer (score 4):

You can decrease code size using itertools:

```
from itertools import chain
return set(chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues()))
```

but i'm not sure if this version readable enough.

Also you can get rid of list and define keys2 as set:

```
keys2 = set([])
for small_d in d.itervalues():
    keys2.update(small_d.keys())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{key for inner in d.values() for key in inner}
```

It is a `set` comprehension - to not include repeated values.
(You may use the  `list()` function to convert it to the list.

---

**The explanation:** *Read it from the end:*
It is the set of each `key` in `inner`, where every `inner` is from the list `d.values()`.